# helm config map from external yaml file

Tags: config, kubernetes-helm, configmap

I want to update my helm dependencies with configurations , declared in central folder ,among microservices .
having the following tree of folders

```
- config-repo
  - application.yml
  - specific.yml
- kubernetes
  - helm
  - common
  - components
    - microservice#1 (templates relating to )
      - config-repo
        - application.yml
        - specefic.yml
      - templates
        - configmap_from_file.yaml
      - values.yaml
      - Chart.yaml
    - microservice#2
    - ...
```

here is the template of microservice#1 configmap_from_file.yaml file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ include "common.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "common.name" . }}
    helm.sh/chart: {{ include "common.chart" . }}
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ .Release.Service }}
data:
{{ (.Files.Glob "config-repo/*").AsConfig | indent 2 }}
{{- end -}}
```

and inside of microservice#1's config-repo files are

**specific.yml**

```
../../../../../config-repo/specific.yml
```

**application.yml**

```
../../../../../config-repo/application.yml
```

*they both are just reference to other files*

when I command `helm dep update .`  and then `helm template . -s templates/configmap_from_file.yaml`

**I expect the following output**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: review
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: review
    helm.sh/chart: review-1.0.0
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
data:
  application.yml: CONTENTS OF THE FILE IN ADDRESS
  specific.yml: CONTENTS OF THE FILE IN ADDRESS
```

**but the following is appeared**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: review
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: review
    helm.sh/chart: review-1.0.0
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
data:
  application.yml: ../../../../../config-repo/application.yml
  specific.yml: ../../../../../config-repo/specific.yml
```

**why just address is injected and not the content are appeared**

Comment: "references" or symlinks? If you `cat config-repo/application.yml` do you see the contents, or you see that `../../..` business?

Comment: dear @mdaniel I'm not familiar with those terms , I just want to mention that configurations should be read from config-repo/application.yml which is central place of configurations .
contents of ```cat config-repo/application.yml``` are whole of the configurations and I see the *contents* there.